# No null pointer exception after calling method of null object

Tags: java, debugging, nullpointerexception, null

I am new to programming, and have been mostly using java. Normally, if I accidently try to call a method from a variable that is null, I get a null pointer exception. However, in one case I found that the program execution just got stuck (was still running, but would not execute any more lines) without ever generating an exception.

What are some reasons that a method call to an object variable that is null would not produce a null pointer exception?

More importantly, how can I avoid this situation in the future, since it would have been much easier to find the problem if a null pointer exception was generated at that line.

Comment: Just as a piece of advise, it will be a lot easier to help you if you post your code so we can see what is going on. So just edit the question and add your code.

Comment: Ok- I'm going to try to replicate the behavior in a smaller test class and paste that here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are some reasons that a method call to an object variable that is
>   null would not **produce** a null pointer exception?

It will always **produce** a NPE. But it's possible to "hide" it, if you catch the exception and do nothing, like this :

```java
MyClass myVar; // myVar is not instanciated
try {
    myVar.myFct(); // NPE is thrown here !
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    // do nothing : **can be dangerous, don't do this ! **
    // basic code here should be at least: npe.printStacktrace();
}
```

In this case, an exception is thrown, but the user (or you) will never see it has been thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd have to see your code to answer for sure, but it likely got stuck in an infinite loop. No one can tell you exactly why without seeing your code.

Next time, just add an if loop to check to make sure the value isn't null.

For example

```
 if ( variableName !== null)
      {
         // work properly
      } 
 else 
       {
            //print out error message
       }
```

You can use exception an exception catch, but I think this is a better way to do it.